# A conjecture on six planes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, conjectures

When I read [Cox's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoxsTheorem.html), and [Clifford's Circle Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliffordsCircleTheorem.html) and [Miquel six circles theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miquel%27s_theorem), I found the conjecture as folowing. And I checked the conjecture by the Geogebra sofware, the conjecture is right. I am looking for a proof of the conjecture.

> **Conjecture:** Let four points $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$ on a plane $\sigma$. Let six planes $\sigma_{12}$, $\sigma_{13}$, $\sigma_{14}$, $\sigma_{23}$, $\sigma_{24}$ such that the plane $\sigma_{ij}$ through two points $P_i$ and $P_j$. Let $P_{ijk}$ be a common points of three planes $\sigma_{ij}, \sigma_{jk}, \sigma_{ki}$. Then show that four points $P_{123}, P_{124}, P_{134}, P_{234}$ lie on a plane.

[See also Cox's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoxsTheorem.html)

[image]

Comment: Unless I misread something, your statement is simply the dual of Cox's theorem as stated on the MathWorld page you provided: so it follows from it by projective duality (or by dualizing the proof). This is not a research-level question.

Comment: I am not sure that I am right. But I get this ideas from Miquel six circles theorem. The Cox's theorem similarly the Clifford circles theorem. The Clifford circles theorem and Miquel six circles theorem is not same. I will think about your comment in one day and reply again. @Gro-Tsen . Thanks to You.

Comment: Dear Mister @Gro-Tsen , the conjecture is not dual of the Cox's theorem.

Comment: The dual of the statement contained in the first half of the MathWorld article "Cox's Theorem" is: «Let $P_1,\ldots,P_4$ be four points in general position on a plane $σ$ and let $σ_{ij}$ be a plane on the line $P_i P_j$. Let $P_{ijk}$ denote the intersection of $σ_{ij},σ_{ik},σ_{jk}$. Then the four points $P_{234},P_{134},P_{124},P_{123}$ are all on one plane $σ_{1234}$.» In what way is this different from the "conjecture" you wrote? Even the notation is the same!

Comment: @Gro-Tsen 1-Yes, see stetement it is dual (seem, methought
, like dual). If you let that it is really dual you must give a proof of the conjecture by Cox's theorem.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen 2-The Miquel six circles theorem statement that: Let four points $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$ on a circle. Let four circles $\sigma_{12}$, $\sigma_{23}$, $\sigma_{34}$, $\sigma_{41}$, such that the circles $\sigma_{ij}$ through two points $P_i$ and $P_j$. Let $\sigma_{ij}$ meets $\sigma_{ik}$ again at $P'_i$ then four points $P'_1, P'_2, P'_3, P'_4$ lie on a circles. But with plane I must add plane $\sigma_{13}$ and $\sigma_{24}$ to get four points  $P'_1, P'_2, P'_3, P'_4$ where $P'_1, P'_2, P'_3, P'_4:=P_{ijk}$

Comment: The dual of any theorem of incidence projective geometry is also a theorem, this doesn't need to be proved anew for each theorem. Read any good textbook on projective geometry (in short, take a nondegenerate quadric and use the polarity w.r.t. this quadric to reduce the theorem to its dual). *Alternatively*, take a purely incidence proof of Cox's theorem and dualize the proof. Again, this is well-known projective geometry, not research: please ask on math.stackexchange.com for more explanations on projective duality if you need, but not here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37718/discussion-between-oai-thanh-dao-and-gro-tsen).

Comment: I think the question was clear, I don't know why it was closed as "unclear what you are asking". Arguably, it is not of research level, but that was not the reason of closing it.